# covariance matrix vs correlation matrix for multiple signal analysis

Tags: time-series, correlation, covariance, cross-correlation, signal-processing

I'm dealing with a set of +100 input signals, and one output. I want to explore how each of the signals affects the output.

**Should I focus on covariance matrix, or correlation matrix, and why?**

I cant find a clear answer on the real interpretation of the elements of both matrices for time series analysis.

Once I focus in one of two matrices, **should I work with plain signals, or with differentiated columns?** Actually, I am interested on how the variations on the input signals affect the output.